# New Google Chrome Beta?

Tags: google-chrome

I currently have Google Chrome dev version installed, however visting http://www.soundstep.com/blog/experiments/jsdetection/, it said I needed to install Google Chrome Beta.

Isn't dev higher than beta?

I thought there was these versions of Google Chrome, from lowest to highest version:

- Stable
- Beta
- Dev
- Canary
- (Chromium)

Is the detection of my browser failing on the website, or have Google Chrome changed their versioning system?

Download link for the "new" chrome beta: https://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Dev on OS X – cannot reproduce. What's your version exactly?

Comment: Just because you are using a dev release does not mean it is newer than *every* beta release. You could be running an old dev release that predates the latest beta. Check for updates (*Wrench Menu->About*)

Comment: Somehow my Google Chrome installation is only version 20.x although it used to be a dev version and now it's the stable version. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a new Chrome tab, open about:flags.

Scroll down to "Enable MediaStream". Note: These options are not in alphabetical order; use Find (Ctrl+F) to find it.

Click Enable.

Restart Chrome.

You can now access the demo web site.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a browser that enables some new features as explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-enabling). To make it simple, I’ve used [Google Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs) !

Hope it helps.